# How to perform operator overloading to avoid if condition in c++?

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
 bool bSign;
 // bSign will be set depending on some criteria, which is omitted here.
 // b[][][] is a float array, which is initialized in the program  
 for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
         for(int k=0; k<10000; k++)
             if(bSign)
                 a[i][j][k] = (b[i][j][k]>500);
             else
                 a[i][j][k] = (b[i][j][k]<500);
```

In the above codes, I have to rely on `bSign` to design the kind of operator (`>` or `<`) I should use to set the output variable `a`. However, I found it costly as it is done within a long `for` loop. Any ideas on how I can escape that?

Comment: I don't see how operator overloading is supposed to get rid of the branch.

Comment: 1) you can not change the language. Overloading the operator for int is simple impossible. 2) the value of bSign is only known during run time. How should operator overloading work, because this takes place during compile time.

Comment: @CinCout: `a` is, presumably, a `bool[1000][10000][10000]`.

Comment: `b` is a `float` array, not `a`. My bad.

Comment: If bsign is set before the loop then branch prediction may save you anyway. However you could assign a function pointer before the loop, with that pointer either pointing at a less than function or a greater than.

Comment: Have you determined that the test actually is costly, for instance by comparing to a loop that always does `a[i][j][k] = (b[i][j][k]>500);`? I would expect the CPU to be able to predict that branch pretty well.

Comment: A decent optimising compiler will notice that bSign is a loop invariant and remove it from the innermost loop.

Comment: And I'd love a machine where this code actually runs, with at least 500 Gigabyte of memory. On my home computer, if I added a bigger hard drive, this would take forever to run because of loading / writing virtual memory from / to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many people said, it is better to move `if` statement out of loops (if it is possible). To prevent code duplication, you can use function pointers, but it may be worse if there will be real calls. Calls cost more than simple `if`. If compiler can inline them, it will be ok.

You also can use templates metaprogramming (simple template algorithm in this case) on this manner:

```
 template<typename ComparatorT>
 void doTheWork(float ***a, const float ***b, ComparatorT comparator)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
             for(int k=0; k<10000; k++)
                 a[i][j][k] = comparator(b[i][j][k], 500);
 }

 ...
 // Usage.
 bool bSign;
 ...
 if (bSign) {
     doTheWork(a, b, std::greater<float>());
 } else {
     doTheWork(a, b, std::larger<float>());
 }
```

Compiler can inline `comparator`'s calls (it is much easier than with function pointers) and it will work almost like you wrote two different loops. The `comparator` object can be really created, but usually it is not significant. One disadvantage is that it often produces hard-to-read code.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler *should* be able to optimise this out if it knows `bSign` won't change during the loop. Making it `const` would help.

If for some reason that's not happening, you could move the `if (bSign)` out to surround the entire set of nested loops. (Basically, doing manually what you're hoping the compiler will do for you.)

Beyond that, you're relying on branch prediction (whose success will depend on the nature of your data).

Operator overloading, though, has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Really, though, this kind of iteration is just not going to be efficient. Can't you find a better algorithm?

Comment: Just thought the same thing, if the values in this huge matrix  matrix can change during runtime, I belive it would be better to store the boolean during change, and not "all at once"

Answer (score 0):

Can you just move the check out of the loop?

```
if (bSign)
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<10000; k++)
                a[i][j][k] = (b[i][j][k]>500);
else
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<10000; k++)
                a[i][j][k] = (b[i][j][k]<500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't get rid of such ifs in your program. But you can help processor to run your program faster. Consider sorting `b` array (or copy & sort if you can't change `b`). This should help to predict branches by processor. Of course make some benchmarks to be sure that won't be worse than your current code.

Comment: If you could sort it then you wouldn't need to perform a comparison on every single element in the first place.

Comment: Well, not for the innermost array anyway. But then sorting only helps you with the innermost array too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is any faster (you'd have to do a perfomance check) but you could avoid all the if statements using a function pointer.

```
int comparisonValue = 500;
auto greater = [comparisonValue](float val) {
    return val > comparisonValue;
};
auto lesser = [comparisonValue](float val) {
    return val < comparisonValue;
};

bool bSign;
// bSign will be set depending on some criteria, which is omitted here.
// b[][][] is a float array, which is initialized in the program  
decltype(greater)* funcPtr;

if(bSign) {
    funcPtr = &greater;
} else {
    funcPtr = &lesser;
}


for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
        for(int k=0; k<10000; k++)
            a[i][j][k] = (*funcPtr)(b[i][j][k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use it like that?;

```
  a[i][j][k] = (bSign == (b[i][j][k] > 500)) && (b[i][j][k] != 500);
```

Comment: It has more complicated ("slower") condition than the instant one.

Comment: You are wrong. "If" is slower. Look at here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820319/why-is-a-cpu-branch-instruction-slow)