# Loading value at address into register

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

As a learning exercise, I've been handwriting assembly. I can't seem to figure out how to load the value of an address into a register.

Semantically, I want to do the following:

```
_start:
        # read(0, buffer, 1)
        mov     $3, %eax            # System call 3 is read
        mov     $0, %ebx            # File handle 0 is stdin
        mov     $buffer, %ecx       # Buffer to write to
        mov     $1, %edx            # Length of buffer
        int     $0x80               # Invoke system call

        lea     (%ecx, %ecx), %edi  # Pull the value at address into %edi
        cmp     $97, %edi           # Compare to 'a'
        je      done
```

I've written a higher-level implementation in C:

```
char buffer[1];
int main()
{
    read(0, buffer, 1);
    char a = buffer[0];
    return (a == 'a') ? 1 : 0;
}
```

But compiling with `gcc -S` produces assembly that doesn't port well into my implementation above.

I think `lea` is the right instruction I should be using to load the value at the given address stored in `%ecx` into `%edi`, but upon inspection in `gdb`, `%edi` contains a garbage value after this instruction is executed. Is this approach correct?

Comment: No, `lea` will give you the effective address, i.e. `ecx + edi`. It looks like you want `mov`, and probably the variant that only reads one byte and zero-extends it into a double-word since you're dealing with ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `lea` instruction, what you need is:

```
movzbl  (%ecx), %edi
```

That is, *zero extending* into the `edi` register the byte at the memory address contained in `ecx`.

```
_start:
        # read(0, buffer, 1)
        mov     $3, %eax            # System call 3 is read
        mov     $0, %ebx            # File handle 0 is stdin
        mov     $buffer, %ecx       # Buffer to write to
        mov     $1, %edx            # Length of buffer
        int     $0x80               # Invoke system call

        movzbl  (%ecx), %edi        # Pull the value at address ecx into edi
        cmp     $97, %edi           # Compare to 'a'
        je      done
```

---

#### Some advice

- You don't really need the `movz` instruction: you don't need a separate load operation, since you can compare the byte in memory pointed by `ecx` directly with `cmp`:

  ```
  cmpb $97, (%ecx)
  ```
- You may want to specify the character to be compared against (i.e., `'a'`) as `$'a'` instead of `$97` in order to improve readability:

  ```
  cmpb $'a', (%ecx)
  ```
- [Avoiding *conditional* branches is usually a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820319/why-is-a-cpu-branch-instruction-slow). Immediately after performing the system call, you could use the following code that uses `cmov` for determining the return value, which is stored in `eax`, instead of performing a conditional jump (i.e., the `je` instruction):

  ```
  xor     %eax, %eax     # set eax to zero
  cmpb    $'a', (%ecx)   # compare to 'a'
  cmovz   %edx, %eax     # conditionally move edx(=1) into eax
  ret                    # eax is either 0 or 1 at this point
  ```

  `edx` was set to `1` prior to the system call. Therefore, this approach above relies on the fact that `edx` is preserved across the system call (i.e., the `int 0x80` instruction).
- Even better, you could use `sete` on `al` after the comparison instead of the `cmov`:

  ```
  xor     %eax, %eax     # set eax to zero
  cmpb    $'a', (%ecx)   # compare to 'a'
  sete    %al            # conditionally set al
  ret                    # eax is either 0 or 1 at this point
  ```

  The register `al`, which was set to zero by means of `xor %eax, %eax`, will be set to `1` if the `ZF` flag was set by the `cmp` (i.e., if the byte pointed by `ecx` is `'a'`). With this approach you don't need to care about thinking whether the syscall preserves `edx` or not, since the outcome doesn't depend on `edx`.

Comment: You missed updating the 2nd example to movzx.  And in that example, I think you want `setz %al`, because you didn't include an instruction to set `%edx` to 1.  (And you don't want to have to do that).  Anyway, `xor`-zero eax / `cmpb $'a', (%ecx)` / `setz %al` should do the trick.  (You can even leave out the xor-zeroing if you only return an 8-bit `bool`, or take advantage of the fact that only the low byte of main's `int` return value is visible as the process's exit status).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the comment. The second code snippet comes *after* performing the system call (i.e., the `int $0x80` instruction). The register `edx` is set to 1 *before* the syscall. I thought that [`edx`'s value is preserved across the syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/8012646). The code also assumes that `ecx`'s value is preserved across the syscall. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't realize this was still *immediately* after the system call, before any other code that might have used `%edx`.  So it's not a stand-alone fragment.  Yes, `int $0x80` preserves all registers except the return value in EAX.  But still prefer `setz` instead of `cmov`, with xor-zeroing before the compare.  The system call dwarfs the cost here, of course, but `cmov` is 2 uops on Intel before Broadwell.  If you needed to produce a 0/1 but it didn't matter what register, `cmov` on EBX and EDX would work because you already have a 0 and 1, and be better on AMD and recent Intel.

Comment: BTW, `sete` has the correct semantic meaning for this case: set if the last compare was `e`qual.  It's a synonym for `setz`, of course, but it helps indicate to human readers what it means for ZF to be set there.