# Compiler optimization of if (loop invariant) if statement inside a loop

Tags: c, loops, optimization, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I have a function like this in C (in pseudo-ish code, dropping the unimportant parts):

```
int func(int s, int x, int *a, int *r) {
    int i;

    // do some stuff

    for (i = 0; i < a_really_big_int; ++i) {
        if (s)
            r[i] = x ^ i;
        else
            r[i] = x ^ a[i];
        // and maybe a couple other ways of computing r
        // that are equally fast individually
    }

    // do some other stuff

}
```

This code gets called so much that this loop is actually a speed bottleneck in the code. I am wondering a couple things:

1. Since the switch `s` is a constant in the function, will good compilers optimize the loop so that the branch isn't slowing things down all the time?
2. If not, what is a good way to optimize this code?

====

**EDIT:** Here is an update with a fuller example:

```
int func(int s,
         int start, int stop, int stride,
         double *x, double *b,
         int *a, int *flips, int *signs, int i_max,
         double *c)
{
  int i,k,st;
  for (k=start; k<stop; k += stride) {
    b[k] = 0;
    for (i=0;i<i_max;++i) {

      /* this is the code in question */
      if (s) st = k^flips[i];
      else st = a[k]^flips[i];
      /* done with code in question */

      b[k] += x[st] * (__builtin_popcount(st & signs[i])%2 ? -c[i] : c[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

In case anyone is curious, I ended up refactoring the code and hoisting the whole inner for loop (with `i_max`) outside, making the `really_big_int` loop be much simpler and hopefully easy to vectorize! (and also avoiding doing a bunch of extra logic a zillion times)

Comment: If possible, do two `if` statements, each containing a loop, instead of a loop containing two `if` statements. Then you only check the condition once, not `a_really_big_int` times. This depends on the other things in your current loop being "extractable" in this way.

Comment: It wouldn't be too much of a stretch for a compiler to optimize this as you want. Why don't you look at the generated assembly to see if it does?

Comment: @hnefatl Doesn't matter for a good compiler.

Comment: @hnefatl right---the reason that I wanted to avoid that is because the actual loop is several nested loops with some not-totally-trivial logic, and I don't want to have to duplicate code a bunch of times. But maybe this is the best solution

Comment: @Barmar good idea--I'll look into it

Comment: Do you have other stuff in the loop that isn't in the `if/else`? The compiler might not want to duplicate all that code just to optimize the `if`.

Comment: @Barmar The example given becomes trivially vectorizable, so `gcc` *absolutely* hoists the `if()` out of the loop.

Comment: Take a look at what options your platform and compiler offer for SIMD or AVX.

Comment: @EOF But maybe his actual code isn't exactly like the example given. He said he left out "unimportant" parts. They might be important to the GCC optimizer.

Comment: I'll update with full example in a sec

Comment: This example invokes an UB anyway for large enough `i` on 32 bit system

Comment: Is it possible to make it parallel? You could split this into 2 data sets and iterate over both in parallel.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I am already parallelizing the crap out of it actually (see my edit)... it *still* is a bottleneck.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Considering that the new code isn't even a compilable function, I've closevoted for lack of [MCVE].

Comment: whoops. I renamed something `s` and forgot that was already my switch. editing...

Comment: @G.Meyer Still not a compileable function.

Comment: @EOF ok, understood. That being said is declaring all variables, etc. really necessary for answering my question? it seems that would just add a bunch of code that aren't really relevant for what the compiler is doing. If you really want me to, I can make it compilable...

Comment: @G.Meyer You can just make all variables be function arguments for all I care. The only point is that I can throw it at my compiler and get a result everybody else can verify (unlike when *I* have to take a hacksaw to your code to test it).

Comment: Ask the compiler to give you assembler, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -S -O2` then look into the generated assembler file  `*.s`

Answer (score 5):

One obvious way to optimize the code is pull the conditional outside the loop:

```
if (s)
    for (i=0;i<a_really_big_int;++i) {
        r[i] = x ^ i;
    }
else
    for (i=0;i<a_really_big_int;++i) {
        r[i] = x ^ a[i];
    }
```

A shrewd compiler might be able to change that into r[] assignments of more than one element at a time.

Comment: A "shrewd compiler" doesn't need the help, it can hoist the `if()` just fine.

Comment: @EOF:  You missed my point.  I am talking about what happens after the `if` is hoisted.

Comment: ... and now it can be vectorized with `_mm*_xor_si*()`, `_mm*_set_epi32()` and unaligned load/stores (unless you can insure the inputs are aligned) , but hopefully the compiler can do it itself

Answer (score 3):

**Micro-optimizations**

Usually they are not worth the time - reviewing larger issue is more effective.

Yet to micro-optimize, trying a variety of approaches and then profiling them to find the best can make for modest improvements.

In addition to [@wallyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615276/2410359) and [@kabanus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615276/2410359) fine answers, some simplistic compilers benefit with a loop that ends in 0.

```
// for (i=0;i<a_really_big_int;++i) {
for (i=a_really_big_int; --i; ) {
```

---

[edit 2nd optimization]

OP added a more compete example.  One of the issues is that the compiler can not make assumption that that the memory pointed to by `b` and others do not overlap.  This prevents certain optimizations.

Assuming they in fact to do not overlap, use `restrict` on `b` to allow optimizations. `const` helps too for weaker compilers that do no deduce that.  `restrict` on the others may also benefit, again, if the reference data does not overlap.

```
// int func(int s, int start, int stop, int stride, double *x,
//     double *b, int *a, int *flips,
//     int *signs, int i_max, double *c) {

int func(int s, int start, int stop, int stride, const double * restrict x,
    double * restrict b, const int * restrict a, const int * restrict flips, 
    const int * restrict signs, int i_max, double *c) {
```

Answer (score 1):

All your commands are quick O(1) command in the loop. The `if` is definitely optimized, so is your for+if if all your commands are of the form `r[i]=somethingquick`. The question may boil down for you on how small can big int be?

A quick `int main` that just goes from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` summing into a long variable, takes ~10 seconds for me on the Ubuntu subsystem on Windows. Your commands may multiply this by a few, which quickly gets to a minute. Bottom line, this may be not be avoidable if you really are iterating a ton.

If `r[i]` are calculated independently, this would be a classic usage for threading/multi-processing.

EDIT:

I think `%` is optimized anyway by the compiler, but if not, take care that `x & 1` is much faster for an odd/even check.

Comment: re: the builtin, I think that depending on your architecture __builtin_popcount is a single machine instruction (from gcc) anyway. I'm not sure though. anyway I really doubt that the hamming weight of an int takes a lot of time to compute...

Comment: @G.Meyer It is (returns the 1s or something). Didn't know for sure it was a single instruction though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x86_64, you can ensure that the pointers are aligned to 16 bytes and use [intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).  If it is only running on systems with AVX2, you could use the __mm256 variants (similar for avx512*)

```
int func(int s, int x, const __m128i* restrict a, __m128i* restrict r) {
    size_t i = 0, max = a_really_big_int / 4;
    __m128i xv =  _mm_set1_epi32(x);
    // do some stuff
    if (s) {
        __m128i iv = _mm_set_epi32(3,2,1,0); //or is it 0,1,2,3?
        __m128i four = _mm_set1_epi32(4);
        for ( ;i<max; ++i, iv=_mm_add_epi32(iv,four)) {
            r[i] = _mm_xor_si128(xv,iv);
        }
    }else{ /*not (s)*/
        for (;i<max;++i){
            r[i] = _mm_xor_si128(xv,a[i]);
        }
    }
    // do some other stuff   
}
```

Comment: Normally you'd take `int *` args and so the intrinsic vector types are an implementation detail inside the function, not something that callers have to cast for.  Also note that the `not(s)` branch only needs AVX1; it doesn't need integer increment, only bitwise, so it could use `_mm256_xor_ps`.  But if you're making a version for CPUs with AVX1 but not AVX2, many of those are Bulldozer family where 256-bit isn't very efficient (and Piledriver specifically has a serious performance bug with 256-bit stores). Or Sandy/Ivy Bridge where cache-line-split 256-bit load/store are extra slow.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `if` statement will be optimized away on any decent compiler (unless you asked the compiler not to optimize), I would consider writing the optimization in (just in case you compile without optimizations).

In addition, although the compiler might optimize the "absolute" `if` statement, I would consider optimizing it manually, either using any available builtin, or [using bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041632/how-to-compute-the-integer-absolute-value) operations.

i.e.

```
b[k] += x[st] *
        ( ((__builtin_popcount(st & signs[I]) & 1) *
           ((int)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)) ^c[I] );
```

This will take the last bit of `popcount` (1 == odd, 0 == even), multiply it by the const (all bits 1 if odd, all bits 0 if true) and than XOR the `c[I]` value (which is the same as `0-c[I]` or `~(c[I])`.

This will avoid instruction jumps in cases where the second `absolute` if statement isn't optimized.

P.S.

I used an 8 byte long value and truncated it's length by casting it to an `int`. This is because I have no idea how long an `int` might be on your system (it's 4 bytes on mine, which is `0xFFFFFFFF`).